# Differing behavior between EventBox and derived class inside Notebook

Tags: c#, inheritance, gtk, gtk#, gtk2

I previously assumed that a class directly derived from another one, without any modifications, would exhibit the same behavior as the base. This appears to not be the case with GTK# event boxes. When enclosed within a Notebook, the background of an EventBox with StateType.Normal differs from that of a custom widget derived from EventBox. This is with VisibleWindow on.

The problem has been reproduced in the code snippet below the compiles to give the output attached as an image. Edit: fixed Window initialization.

```
class TestBox : EventBox {
}

class MainClass {
    public static void Main (string[] args) {
        Application.Init();

        Window win = new Window(WindowType.Toplevel);
        Table table = new Table(2, 2, true);

        Notebook notebook1 = new Notebook();
        notebook1.ModifyBg(StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color(255, 0, 0));
        notebook1.AppendPage(GetTestPair(), new Label("Test"));
        table.Attach(notebook1, 0, 1, 0, 1);

        Notebook notebook2 = new Notebook();
        notebook2.AppendPage(GetTestPair(), new Label("Test"));
        table.Attach(notebook2, 1, 2, 0, 1);

        EventBox eventbox = new EventBox();
        eventbox.ModifyBg(StateType.Normal, new Gdk.Color(255, 0, 0));
        eventbox.Add(GetTestPair());
        table.Attach(eventbox, 0, 1, 1, 2);

        table.Attach(GetTestPair(), 1, 2, 1, 2);

        win.Add(table);
        win.ShowAll();
        Application.Run();
    }

    public static Widget GetTestPair () {
        HBox boxes = new HBox { BorderWidth = 5 };
        EventBox box1 = new EventBox() { Child = new Frame("EventBox") };
        TestBox box2 = new TestBox() { Child = new Frame("TestBox") };
        boxes.PackStart(box1);
        boxes.PackStart(box2);
        return boxes;
    }
}
```

The output on my Macbook Air below. Each quarter of the window contains a EventBox/TestBox pair side-by-side for comparison. The first row shows them directly attached to the table (identical behavior as expected); the second row shows them in Notebooks that are then attached to the table (clearly different backgrounds as seen). The first column has been given a red background for clarity and contrast.

[image: Output of the example code showing the issue.]

Does anyone know why this happens, or if there is any workaround to standardize the background colors? Thanks.

Comment: An **EventBox** is used in order to give a Gtk widget without window a way to capture events...  Why are you using it? In any case, an **EventBox** does not draw anything on the screen, so it cannot be the source of your problems.

Comment: I have both compiled your code and made my own tests, and see no difference. I'm using Linux, though. As a side note, your code does not compile because Window needs to be passed Gtk.WindowType.TopLevel in the constructor... What version of Gtk# are you using?

Comment: Ah. I use Visual Studio. I made a few changes trying to replace the MainWindow custom class VS puts in a new project and I guess I messed something up. Anyway, I was referring to this: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkEventBox.html#gtk-event-box-set-visible-window.

Comment: I want to use a visible window because I'm using it to emulation button behavior, and setting the state does nothing if visiblewindow is false. @Baltasarq

Comment: If it's OS specific and probably not intended behavior, should I make a bug report?

Comment: Yep, I guess you should. However, I'm not sure if someone is going to fix that anytime soon. Can you force the background you want, or maybe force it in those widgets without problems?

Comment: I could, but I don't think it's recommended to go around changing backgrounds to "prettify" a UI as it'll mess everything up for a user with a different style.

Comment: This could be something to do with construction. Your default constructor for TestBox (implicit) will be calling the zero-parameter constructor on EventBox (as if base() was called). This may be inappropriate or setting up the EventBox incorrectly.